# Are left out fields by C++ 20 designated initialization guaranteed to be zero initialized?

Tags: c++, c++20

When using C++ 20 designated intializers it is not required to specify a value for every field:

```
struct Foo
{
    int i;
    void* p;
};
```

can be initialized like this:

```
Foo bar = {
    .i = 22
};
```

Are the left out fields zero-intialized? So in this example is `p` guaranteed to be set to `nullptr`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Are the left out fields zero-intialized?

In this case, yes. The rule is (from [[dcl.init]/5](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#aggr-5)):

> For a non-union aggregate, each element that is not an explicitly initialized element is initialized as follows:
>
> - If the element has a default member initializer ([class.mem]), the element is initialized from that initializer.
> - Otherwise, if the element is not a reference, the element is copy-initialized from an empty initializer list ([dcl.init.list]).
> - Otherwise, the program is ill-formed.

In this case `p` is not explicitly initialized. It has no default member initializer, so we fall to the second bullet. It is not a reference, so it is copy-initialized from `{}`. For a `void*`, that's zero-initialization.

Answer (score 0):

The fields left out are:

> default member initializers where provided, empty list-initialization otherwise

source: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization